# Set focus to already opened tab in Internet Explorer - get it to foreground using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure a way to get focus of tab in Internet Explorer. I've done some research and found that there is no simple way of doing it.

In the code that is written below, I check for already open tabs that meet a certain criteria and if any of them is found I use it to navigate to a webpage. If there is no webpage that meets the criteria, I open a new tab. Afterwards, I want to get that tab to foreground.

Using `SetForegroundWindow` is a basic and incomplete approach as it sets any of the Internet Explorer windows to foreground. For example, if I have multiple windows open, with multiple tabs each, it is possible to get another instance of Internet Explorer Window to foreground, not the one containing the tab I need.
Also, I've tried using `mshtml` to get focus of the tab, but it doesn't work.

So far, I have been using `SHDocVw` to Navigate in Internet Explorer. As a limitation, I cannot use any of the available automation alternatives, such as Selenium Webdriver.

What approach should I take? In the worst case scenario, I am thinking about using `SendKeys` to navigate through open tabs, but I would like a better approach.

```
public static void openwebpage()
            {
            start:
            InternetExplorer ie = null;
            ShellWindows allBrowser = new ShellWindows();//get all windows
            int browserCount = -1;
            List<int> tabs = new List<int>(); // list containing shellwindows that meet certain criteria - InternetExplorer and webapp ip
            tabs.Clear();
            foreach (InternetExplorer browser in allBrowser)
            {
                browserCount++;
                ie = allBrowser.Item(browserCount) as InternetExplorer;
                if (ie != null && ie.FullName.ToLower().Contains("iexplore.exe") && ie.LocationURL.Contains(Properties.Settings.Default["adresa"].ToString())) // requirements for identifying open local webapp pages
                {
                    tabs.Add(browserCount);
                }
            }
            bool gasit = false;
            foreach (var tab in tabs)
            {
                ie = allBrowser.Item(tab) as InternetExplorer;
                if (ie.LocationURL.Contains("main.aspx")) //if the tab is in the main interface - use that tab to navigate
                {
                    gasit = true;
                    ie.Navigate2(Properties.Settings.Default["adresa"] + + "?id_dosar=" + IDdosar);
                    ie = allBrowser.Item(tab) as InternetExplorer;
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)ie.HWND); //get ie to foreground
                    ((HTMLDocument)ie.Document).focus(); 

                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!gasit) // if neither of the tabs is in the main interface (main.aspx), open a new tab
            {
                ie.Navigate2(Properties.Settings.Default["adresa"] + "?id_dosar=" + IDdosar, 65536/* 0x0800*/);// 0800 e cu focus, 0x1000 fara focus
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                ie = allBrowser.Item(tabs.LastOrDefault() + 1) as InternetExplorer;
                SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)ie.HWND);
                ((HTMLDocument)ie.Document).focus();
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

No easy way i guess.This is not a clear way, but hopefully you can work with it

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("Internet");

if (procs.Length == 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("internet is not currently open");
}

List<string> titles = new List<string>();
IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
int id = 0;
int numTabs = procs.Length;

foreach (Process p in procs)
{
  if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
  {
    hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
    id = p.Id;
    break;
  }
}

bool isMinimized = IsIconic(hWnd);
if (isMinimized)
{
  ShowWindow(hWnd, 9); // restore
  Thread.Sleep(100);
}

SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
SendKeys.SendWait("^+1"); // change focus to first tab
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I don't understand a few things in the code. You declare `numTabs` and `id` as int,  but you don't use them afterwards. What are their purpose in the logic of the code? Anyway, `procs.Length` is 0, even if there are open internet pages.